# storing html image tag in database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a content management system that allows the user to generate html which is then stored in a database.

Everything works as expected except images. When I inspect the image elements with the dev tools the url appears correct. However, if I click the url the browser prefixes the image url with the url of the current page.

So for example:

Current Page: testProject.com/code/pages/index.php

Image url : `http://testProject.com/code/pages/images/image_1.jpg`

If i click the url in chrome dev tools I end up with the following url in the address bar:

```
testProject.com/code/page//"http:/testProject.com/code/pages/images/images_1.jpg/"
```

I'm relatively new to programming so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What code is used for the html generation?

Comment: You've got quotes in there, so you're probably doing something like `<img src='"http://...../images_1.jpg"' />`

Comment: Post a snippet of the actual generated code for the image including the src.

Comment: Please post the code you are using. Is the trailing `/` after `images_1.jpg` a typo, or are you actually using it in your code?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you’re storing the HTML tag, and not just the path to the file?

Comment: The html is generated using the TinyMCE plugin. If somebody wants to upload an image from their local machine an image element is generated using javascript and place into the TinyMCE editor. This allows users to see the uploaded image in the editor immediately. TinyMCE generated html and image elements are sent and saved to the database together as one block of html.

Comment: <img id="\" news_story_image\"" src="\" http://testProject.com/code/pages/images/image_1.jpg\"" alt="\"animal_pic\"">

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `src` path is correct.

It should be:

`<img src="http://project.com/path/to/image.jpg" />`

no extra quotes, two slashes in `http://`

or

`<img src="/path/to/image.jpg" />`

- the first "/" making it an "absolute path"

Comment: Typo. `src="/path/to/image.jpg"` and not `src="/path/to/image.jpg:`

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply `str_replace()` to remove the extra characters:

```
 str_replace("testProject.com/code/page//", "", "$your_link");
```

Comment: The image tag is returned within a block of html so might be a bit messy using str_replace